# In SSRS, how can I add a row to aggregate all the rows that don't match a filter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on a report that shows transactions grouped by type.

```
  Type    Total income  
 ------- -------------- 
  A                575  
  B                244  
  C                128  
  D                 45  
  E                  5  
  F                  3  
  Total           1000
```

I only want to provide details for transaction types that represent more than 10% of the total income (i.e. A-C). I'm able to do this by applying a filter to the group:

```
  Type    Total income  
 ------- -------------- 
  A                575  
  B                244  
  C                128  
  Total           1000
```

What I want to display is a single row just above the total row that has a total for all the types that have been filtered out (i.e. the sum of D-F):

```
  Type    Total income  
 ------- -------------- 
  A                575  
  B                244  
  C                128  
  Other             53  
  Total           1000
```

Is this even possible? I've tried using running totals and conditionally hidden rows within the group. I've tried `Iif` inside `Sum`. Nothing quite seems to do what I need and I'm butting up against scope issues (e.g. "the value expression has a nested aggregate that specifies a dataset scope").

If anyone can give me any pointers, I'd be really grateful.

---

**EDIT:** Should have specified, but at present the dataset actually returns individual transactions:

```
  ID   Type   Amount  
 ---- ------ -------- 
   1   A           4  
   2   A           2  
   3   B           6  
   4   A           5  
   5   B           5
```

The grouping is done using a row group in the tablix.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to solve that in the SQL source of your dataset instead of inside SSRS:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN CAST([Total income] AS FLOAT) / SUM([Total income]) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) >= 0.10  THEN [Type]
    ELSE 'Other'
  END AS [Type]
  , [Total income]
FROM Source_Table
```

See also [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef8b8/1/0)

Comment: Thanks - this is very similar to the approach I had resorted to, but in effect (for this particular report) it means maintaining a separate dataset for each tablix - not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve this in SQL, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40118/4/0).

```
SELECT I.*
,(
  CASE
    WHEN I.TotalIncome >= (SELECT Sum(I2.TotalIncome) / 10 FROM Income I2) THEN 10
    ELSE 1
  END 
) AS TotalIncomePercent

FROM Income I
```

After this, create two sum groups.

- SUM(TotalIncome * TotalIncomePercent) / 10
- SUM(TotalIncome * TotalIncomePercent)

Second approach may be to use calculated column in SSRS. Try to create a calculated column with above case expression. If it allows you to create it, you may use it in the same way as SQL approach.

Comment: Thanks - see my comment in response to the answer from @vstrien.

Comment: @TomWright I suggested one more approach. But I am not sure if it is feasible. I do not have SSRS right now.

Comment: Ah! A thousand apologies - I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

1) To show income greater than 10% use row visibility condition like
=iif(reportitems!total_income.value/10<= I.totalincome,true,false)
here reportitems!total_income.value is total of all income  textbox value which will be total value of detail group.
 and I.totalincome is current field value.

2)add one more row to outside of detail group to achieve other income and use expression as 
  = reportitems!total_income.value-sum(iif(reportitems!total_income.value/10<= I.totalincome,I.totalincome,nothing))